# How to set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" for a "config" module divided into common, local, production files

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I'm setting up a wsgi.py to deploy my django app in DigitalOcean, but I'm getting the following errors during deployment phase after successful build. From the error trace, I think there is a problem with `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config")` this line inside wsgi.py.

My config files are organized as a python module with common, local, and production settings. I'm not sure where and how to fix this problem, and I've been stuck here for a few days now. Would appreciate any input!

#### ERROR TRACE

```
[2022-07-31 03:29:55] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 908, in _find_spec
[2022-07-31 03:29:55] AttributeError: 'ConfigurationImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'
[2022-07-31 03:29:55] 
[2022-07-31 03:29:55] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2022-07-31 03:29:55] 
[2022-07-31 03:29:55] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     worker.init_process()
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     self.load_wsgi()
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     self.callable = self.load()
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     return self.load_wsgiapp()
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/code/scraft-server/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application  # noqa
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/configurations/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     self._setup(name)
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/configurations/importer.py", line 133, in find_module
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     imp.find_module(module, path))
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 296, in find_module
[2022-07-31 03:29:55]     raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
[2022-07-31 03:29:55] ImportError: No module named 'config'
```

#### file tree

```
monorepo/backend-server
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── common.py
│   ├── local.py
│   └── production.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── urls.py
├── wait_for_postgres.py
└── wsgi.py
```

#### wsgi.py

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_CONFIGURATION", "Production")

# sys.path.append("/scraft-server")

from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application  # noqa

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

#### config.common.py

```
import os
from os.path import join
from distutils.util import strtobool
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import datetime
import dj_database_url
from configurations import Configuration

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

load_dotenv()

class Common(Configuration):

    # settings
```

#### DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Allows docker to cache installed dependencies between builds
COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Adds our application code to the image
WORKDIR /code/scraft-server
COPY scraft-server .  
WORKDIR /code

EXPOSE 8000

# Run the production server
CMD newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn --bind localhost:$PORT --access-logfile - scraft-server.wsgi:application
```

## EDIT

Editted DockerFile to the following:

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE backend-server.config.production
ENV DJANGO_CONFIGURATION Production
# ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE backend-server.config.production

# Allows docker to cache installed dependencies between builds
COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Adds our application code to the image
WORKDIR /code/backend-server
COPY backend-server .  
WORKDIR /code

EXPOSE 8000

# Run the production server
CMD newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn --bind localhost:$PORT --access-logfile - backend-server.wsgi:application
```

#### New Error Log

```
-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/code/scraft-server/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application  # noqa
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/configurations/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 223, in create
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     import_module(entry)
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[2022-07-31 05:49:23]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[2022-07-31 05:49:23] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'
```

Answer (score 0):

in your dockerfile, use an environment variable such as

```
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE backend-server.config.production
```

Comment: I used environment variables as per your suggestion, but I'm not getting a ModuleNotFoundError for one of my apps in INSTALLED_APPS. please refer to my edit to the original question

Comment: In your common configuration, add all installed apps and from your production file import your common configuration.

Comment: Yup, that's what I did before but still giving me the same error :(